# Which thread does the variable belong to?

Tags: java, multithreading, variables

I hava some code like this:

```
class LooperThread extends Thread {
    public Handler mHandler;

    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();

        mHandler = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                  // process incoming messages here
            }
        };

        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

I want to know which thread the "mHandler" belong to?

Add: Is it different if I declare(or instance it) in different thread.

Comment: Your question does not make sense. The `mHanlder` is only defined. It is not yet used in any thread. An object does not 'belong' to a thread.

Comment: `Looper` class is irrelevant in your code snippet, please remove it for clarity.

Comment: Is your question, from which thread is it safe to modify/access the mHandler variable? Or are you are you asking which thread `handleMessage` gets called on?

Comment: Is it different if I declare(or instance it) in different thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't belong to **any** thread. It is public so any thread can access it and modify. That being said it is crucial to make it thread safe (your code isn't - the variable isn't `volatile`).

The bottom line is - every object created using `new` operator is placed on the heap which is shared among all the threads. Other threads can access the object reference e.g. if it is not encapsulated like in your example or exposed on purpose.

Technically speaking - in Java any object does not belong to any other - all references to a given object are equal. And when the last reference to the object (huge oversimplification) are gone, it is garbage collected. So one can say: the last reference *owns* the object.

Comment: Is it different if I declare(or instance it) in different thread?

Comment: No, from Java/JVM perspective it doesn't really matter in which thread you have created an object. Once it is initialized and constructor was executed a reference to that object can be equally used by any thread that can access it.

Answer (score 1):

Threads can access all fields.  Only local variables exist only in one thread.

If you want to access the thread in the out block you can use. `LooperThread.this`

Answer (score 0):

Because `Handler` is an inner class, it can access the outer class using this syntax:

```
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // process incoming messages here
            Thread t = LooperThread.this;
        }
```

From there you should know what to do.

Please note: The instance of `Thread` is an object. But *the thread* in which the code is executed is a completely other thing. Don't confuse the representant `Thread` with the actual thing (CPU resource).

Answer (score 0):

try using this inside  your handleMessage method

```
Thread.currentThread().getName()
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you're asking is "From which threads is it safe to access/modify the variable `mHandle`?", right now,  your code does not do any locking around the assignment

```
mhandle = ...
```

so it would only be safe to access it from the looper thread. So if you had another piece of code on another thread checking

```
if (looperThread.mhandle == null) {
}
```

this would be not thread-safe. You'd have to lock around both the assignment and the access

```
synchronized (this) {
    mhandle = ...
}
....
synchronized (looperThread) {
    if (looperThread.mHandle == null) {
    }
}
```

On the other hand, if you are asking on which thread `handleMessage` is being called, it appears from the structure of the code that it is being called on the looper thread -- it looks like `Looper.loop()` goes into a loop, waits for messages and then calls `handleMessage()` when a message arrives. Just a guess, though.

Just remember that a variable doesn't actually belong to a thread -- it can be accessed from any thread. The real question is, when is it safe to access it from which threads?